# Setting fonts in preamble

Tags: fonts

I would like to know, how should I configure so that my latex configuration will set as follow:

- For sections and sub-sections, the font is san-serif.
- For contents, the font is Computer Modern and Latin Modern

I'm specifically interested in configuring like one article in this [link](http://opus.bib.hochschule-bonn-rhein-sieg.de/opus-3.3/volltexte/2011/5/)  regarding the fonts used.

How to set it in my preamble, so that I don't need to configure it over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standard document classes (e.g. `article`), use `titlesec` package or `sectsty` pacakage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Blah bla.
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Blah bla.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} %adjust
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\section{Blub}
text text text

\end{document}
```

Read the documentation of the class (scrguide) to learn how to change the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the titlesec package. There are many opportunities for a change of the headline's layout.